# Matplotlib scattered plots inside a nested for loop

Tags: matplotlib, nested-loops, scatter-plot

I have 2 folders, each of them contain 2 files:

```
./folder_222/116.5.dat
./folder_222/118.1.dat

./folder_444/116.5.dat
./folder_444/118.1.dat
```

(116.5 and 118.1 represent a volume)

I would like to create a 2 row, 1 column subplot graph, where:

```
Upper Graph:     
     Title: V = 116.5
     Contains the plot of:
     folder_222/116.5.dat
     folder_444/116.5.dat

Lower Graph: 
     Title: V = 118.1    
     Contains the plot of:
     folder_222/118.1.dat
     folder_444/118.1.dat
```

The best way I thought about is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

# Folders, files and volumes:
folder_222 = './folder_222'
folder_444 = './folder_444'

files_222 = ["116.5.dat",\
"118.1.dat"]

files_444 = ["116.5.dat",\
"118.1.dat"]

vols = ["116.5",\
"118.1"]

fig = plt.figure()

# Generation of the subplots, and the title:    
for indx_vols in range(1, len(vols)+1):
    print '    indx_vols = ', indx_vols
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(vols), 1, indx_vols)
    ax.set_title('V = ' + vols[indx_vols-1], fontsize=10) 

    # For a given subplot, now plot x and y:
    for indx_files in range(len(vols)):

        print 'indx_files = ', indx_files
        x_222, y_222 = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(folder_222, files_222[indx_files]), skiprows = 1).T
        x_444, y_444 = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(folder_444, files_444[indx_files]), skiprows = 1).T
        print 'y_222 = ', y_222, 'x_222 = ', x_222
        print 'y_444 = ', y_444, 'x_444 = ', x_444
        ax.scatter(x_222, y_222, color='k', marker='o', label='222')
        ax.scatter(x_444, y_444, color='m', marker='o', label='444')
```

If you run the program with all these print statements, is possible to see that that the program is doing what expected:

```
    indx_vols =  1
indx_files =  0
y_222 =  [ 1086.  2328.  3633.  3387.  1278.] x_222 =  [  89.  629.  694.  785.  882.]
y_444 =  [ 2262.  3876.  1119.  4338.  2817.] x_444 =  [  753.  1291.   372.  1445.   938.]
indx_files =  1
y_222 =  [ 1353.   903.  4695.   429.  4641.] x_222 =  [  450.   300.  1564.   142.  1546.]
y_444 =  [ 3102.  1335.    57.  1962.  2958.] x_444 =  [ 1033.   444.    18.   653.   985.]
    indx_vols =  2
indx_files =  0
y_222 =  [ 1086.  2328.  3633.  3387.  1278.] x_222 =  [  89.  629.  694.  785.  882.]
y_444 =  [ 2262.  3876.  1119.  4338.  2817.] x_444 =  [  753.  1291.   372.  1445.   938.]
indx_files =  1
y_222 =  [ 1353.   903.  4695.   429.  4641.] x_222 =  [  450.   300.  1564.   142.  1546.]
y_444 =  [ 3102.  1335.    57.  1962.  2958.] x_444 =  [ 1033.   444.    18.   653.   985.]
```

However, there is no difference between both subpots:

[image]

It is like if only one volume-data set was considered.

I would appreciate if you could help me

Here the files to run the code:

```
./folder_222/116.5.dat:

# x   y
89   1086 
629  2328
694  3633
785  3387
882  1278

./folder_222/118.1.dat:

# x  y
450  1353
300  903
1564 4695
142  429
1546 4641

./folder_444/116.5.dat:

# x   y
753  2262
1291 3876
372  1119
1445 4338
938  2817

./folder_444/118.1.dat:

# x  y
1033  3102
444   1335
18    57
653   1962
985   2958
```

Comment: You are plotting all of the file's contents to both plots. Instead you would want to plot only those files which are of a given voltage to each plot. Hence the inner loop should be omitted.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot, you're right. I have been thinking a possible solution: Omitting the inner loop and create a `zip` for loop instead of nested for loop. Please see the answer. Perhaps there is a smarter way. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, all file's contents are plotted to both plots.

Perhaps, there is a smarter way, but a possible solution I have been thinking is to replace the nested for loop by a `zip` for loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

folder_222 = './folder_222'
folder_444 = './folder_444'

files_222 = ["116.5.dat",\
"118.1.dat"]

files_444 = ["116.5.dat",\
"118.1.dat"]

vols = ["116.5",\
"118.1"]

fig = plt.figure()

for indx_vols, indx_files in zip(range(1, len(vols)+1), range(len(vols))):
    print '    indx_vols = ', indx_vols
    ax = fig.add_subplot(len(vols), 1, indx_vols)
    ax.set_title('V = ' + vols[indx_vols-1], fontsize=10) 

    print 'indx_files = ', indx_files
    x_222, y_222 = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(folder_222, files_222[indx_files]), skiprows = 1).T
    x_444, y_444 = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(folder_444, files_444[indx_files]), skiprows = 1).T
    print 'y_222 = ', y_222, 'x_222 = ', x_222
    print 'y_444 = ', y_444, 'x_444 = ', x_444
    ax.scatter(x_222, y_222, color='k', marker='o', label='222')
    ax.scatter(x_444, y_444, color='m', marker='o', label='444')


fig.set_facecolor('w')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The print statements now show that each volume plot will contain a unique data set `(x_222, y_222)` and `(x_444, y_444)`:

```
    indx_vols =  1
indx_files =  0
y_222 =  [ 1086.  2328.  3633.  3387.  1278.] x_222 =  [  89.  629.  694.  785.  882.]
y_444 =  [ 2262.  3876.  1119.  4338.  2817.] x_444 =  [  753.  1291.   372.  1445.   938.]
    indx_vols =  2
indx_files =  1
y_222 =  [ 1353.   903.  4695.   429.  4641.] x_222 =  [  450.   300.  1564.   142.  1546.]
y_444 =  [ 3102.  1335.    57.  1962.  2958.] x_444 =  [ 1033.   444.    18.   653.   985.]
```

[image]